# Prevent from running a js file in all the indexed pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm coding a website with multiple pages (indexed to the index.html) with different content but **one header** and **one footer**. The problem is that I linked my footer.js file to all the pages (considering that it needs the same code) but the issue is that it's loading simultaneously when loading multiple pages.

It's a jquery pop-up so when I click to display it in index.html, it's also displayed in contact.html

I don't want to modify my code for every single page, specially because it will be dynamic after.

So here's my javascript :

```js
//open popup
$('.cdv').on('click', function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 $('.cd-popup').addClass('is-visible');
});

//close popup
$('.cd-popup').on('click', function(event){
 if( $(event.target).is('.cd-popup-close') || $(event.target).is('.cd-popup') ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).removeClass('is-visible');
 }
});

//close popup when clicking the esc keyboard button
$(document).keyup(function(event){
   if(event.which=='27'){
    $('.cd-popup').removeClass('is-visible');
    }
  });


//open popup
$('.pdq').on('click', function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 $('#cd-popup-politique').addClass('is-visible');
});

//close popup
$('#cd-popup-politique').on('click', function(event){
 if( $(event.target).is('.cd-popup-close') || $(event.target).is('#cd-popup-politique') ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).removeClass('is-visible');
 }
});

//close popup when clicking the esc keyboard button
$(document).keyup(function(event){
   if(event.which=='27'){
    $('#cd-popup-politique').removeClass('is-visible');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't really understand the setup. Do you render one page that is a combination of different html files, loading the same script several times, or do you simulatanuously(?) load different pages (in different tabs or windows), each with their proper html file? In the latter case I don't see how a click in one page could have any effect in the other pages (since they are in different tabs/windows). Maybe it is your use of the word "page" that confuses me.

Comment: here's the deal :

index.html > running footer.js
contact.html > running footer.js 
dispo.html > running footer.js 
...

footer.js > one single file running on all the pages which are all connected (linked) to the index.html file

Comment: and yes, when i click on the link on the first tab (which shows a popup) the popup also shows in the all the other tabs

Comment: Do you mean browser tabs? They should have their own (document) scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for the help but I think that I solved the problem.

Actually what's causing this bug is Codekit (I use it to compile my SASS files and to minify js files). I can't explain why but when I tried it locally without the software and pushed it to github to see if it works, than it worked.

So if someone can explain it will be great, otherwise for all those who are facing the same problem, just don't care about codekit if you're running it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways, the first is checking the url pathname and executing code to show a popup only if it meets your criteria

```
var location = window.location.pathname;

// assume it's an index page
if (location === '/') {

  // execute your code to show a popup

}
```

If your pathname will contain `GET` attributes, use `.indexOf()` instead

For this solution you will need to compare `pathname` to either `/` or `index.html`, depending on your server set-up.

Second solution might be a global variable in `.html` file, for example just before you include your main javascript file.

```
<script>
window.popup = true;
</script>
```

And then you can check inside your javascript if this variable has a `true` value and execute your code.

```
if (window.popup === true) {

// show popup

}
```

Documentation: [Window.location - mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I tried it and it doesn't work. I'm not very familiar with javascript, I only use jquery for front-end. So, are you sure that .popup is a valid function because i searched on the internet and didn't get anything or should I replace it with something specific ?

Comment: Same thing for the first method, and fyi location is a global variable so we can't use so I just change it, still not work

Comment: `.popup` in my code is not a function, it's just a parameter I'm assigning to `window` object and I've used `popup` name just as an example, it can be anything so yes, you can name it however you like, and after that you can access `window.popup` anywhere in your code.